# Notice: Undefined Variable, but PHP shouldn't require variable definitions?

Tags: php

I have an extension in Magento that is causing a bug in the system.log

The error message is below. It is at the return statement after the foreach statement

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: struct
```

The method is

```
 public function getFeeList($id)
 {
    //some code here but no statement that contains $struct
    foreach($result2 as $kk=>$vv)
    {
                    $struct[$vv['magikfees_id']]['tax_apply']=$vv['tax_apply'];
                    $struct[$vv['magikfees_id']]['tax_type']=$vv['tax_type'];
      ....
    }
    return $struct;
}
```

To my understanding is that you do not need to declare the PHP variables. So one question is

1. is the scope of the $struct variable in this case only in the foreach? OR

   the code never gets in the foreach statement so $struct is not initialized?
2. is declaring it before the foreach going to resolve this issue? How can I declare it?
3. is the code actually working regardless of this notice?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare PHP variables, but you will get a notice when you don't. You can declare it as `$struct = array();`.

The code will work, but as `$struct` wasn't declared, it is likely you made a mistake (maybe a typo). PHP warns you for that by sending a notice. Although it does work without the declaration, it is recommended to declare it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, the scope is the method `getFeeList()`. Once you've defined the variable you can access it later in your code in that particular method. If the code doesn't enter the `foreach`, the variable will be `null`.
2. Yes it will remove the notice error. You can do that by adding `$struct = array();` before your `foreach`. Another workaround is to remove `E_NOTICE` from your `error_reporting` setting in `php.ini` or set `ini_set()` in the beginning of your code.
3. This particular piece of code should be working just fine even if you haven't defined the variable.

Although in PHP you are not required to define your variables it's a better coding practice to define them.